# Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

Tags: php, arrays

When I use my script at localhost, everything works well, but when I use parse by DOM on paid webhosting, script doesn't work with this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in /www/data/showData.php on line 69
```

On line 69 is this:

```
if(strpos($node->childNodes[$i]->childNodes[$j]->nodeValue,"Soutěž") > -1) $soutez = $node->childNodes[$i]->childNodes[($j+2)]->nodeValue;
```

May I ask you, where the problem could be?

Thank you!

Comment: You should try `$dump = (is_object($node->childNodes) ? get_class($node->childNodes) : gettype($node->childNodes)).$i;var_dump($dump);` on line 68 and see what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

The childNodes property is a DOMNodelist. To access an item in a DOMNodelist, it's like

```
$node->childNodes->item($i)
```

Comment: May I ask you for example? I try this: if(strpos($node->childNodes->item($i)->childNodes[$j]->nodeValue,"Soutěž") > -1) $soutez = $node->childNodes->item($i)->childNodes[($j+2)]->nodeValue; - and still samy error. Thank you!

Comment: Because you're still doing `->childNodes[$j]` and `->childNodes[($j+2)]` instead of `childNodes->item($j)` and `childNodes->item($j+2)`